# Enabling CORS on nginx

Tags: nginx, cors, swagger-ui

I have followed [this](https://michielkalkman.com/snippets/nginx-cors-open-configuration/) example to enable CORS on my API subdomain so that I can send requests to it from SwaggerUI. This is the output I get from running OPTIONS on that subdomain:

```
curl -i -X OPTIONS http://api.MYDOMAIN.com/v1/data/extraction

HTTP/1.1 204 No Content
Server: nginx/1.10.3 (Ubuntu)
Date: Wed, 18 Apr 2018 20:45:52 GMT
Connection: keep-alive
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true
Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, POST, OPTIONS
Access-Control-Allow-Headers: DNT,X-CustomHeader,Keep-Alive,User-Agent,X-Requested-With,If-Modified-Since,Cache-Control,Content-Type,X-API-Key
Access-Control-Max-Age: 1728000
Content-Type: text/plain charset=UTF-8
Content-Length: 0
```

I'm stuck on where to go to figure out why in Chrome on my docs subdomain (same DOMAIN.com server) it [image: CORS error] still gives me this. Can anyone advise where I should look to?

Comment: I figured it was not the add_header but the more_set_headers command. Now the issue is that X-API-KEY header not being sent by the SwaggerUI...

Comment: And the last piece of the puzzle was the suggestion of the darrenleeweber at https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-ui/issues/1244 discussion, the part where it needs to be specified in the "security" part. Thanks to all, question closed!

Comment: Consider posting your findings as an answer instead of in the comments section.

Comment: Indeed will do, its already 2AM here, need to get some sleep first :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All it came down to the fact that NGINX had used ***more_set_headers*** instead of ***add_header*** (it may've been that NGINX had this module enabled) and after that using one of the above examples with it made it working.

Answer (score 4):

I had a similar issue and couldn't get it to work. This setup finally worked for me. https://gist.github.com/Stanback/7145487 this is what it looks like. I just set `$cors 'true'` to test if it worked. It worked for me. This is all in the /location {...} area

```
set $cors '';
    if ($http_origin ~ '^https?://(localhost|www\.yourdomain\.com|www\.yourotherdomain\.com)') {
            set $cors 'true';
    }

    if ($cors = 'true') {
            add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' "$http_origin" always;
            add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Credentials' 'true' always;
            add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Methods' 'GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS' always;
            add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Headers' 'Accept,Authorization,Cache-Control,Content-Type,DNT,If-Modified-Since,Keep-Alive,Origin,User-Agent,X-Requested-With' always;
            # required to be able to read Authorization header in frontend
            #add_header 'Access-Control-Expose-Headers' 'Authorization' always;
    }

    if ($request_method = 'OPTIONS') {
        add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' "$http_origin" always;
            add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Credentials' 'true' always;
            add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Methods' 'GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS' always;
            add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Headers' 'Accept,Authorization,Cache-Control,Content-Type,DNT,If-Modified-Since,Keep-Alive,Origin,User-Agent,X-Requested-With' always;
            # required to be able to read Authorization header in frontend
            #add_header 'Access-Control-Expose-Headers' 'Authorization' always;
            # Tell client that this pre-flight info is valid for 20 days
            add_header 'Access-Control-Max-Age' 1728000;
            add_header 'Content-Type' 'text/plain charset=UTF-8';
            add_header 'Content-Length' 0;
            return 204;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You might want to test a call to api.MYDOMAIN.com/v1/data/extraction with curl and a CORS origin header.

```
curl -i -X POST -H "Origin: http://docs.whatever.com" \
 --verbose http://api.MYDOMAIN.com/v1/data/extraction
```

The response should come back with the header:

Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *

If that header does not come back with the response, chrome will throw an error like what you saw.

P.S. there is a mention in the error that nginx responded with a 404, which might have something to do with it.

Comment: It does come back with the header now, I was adding the wrong command for the nginx.

Answer (score 0):

The problem might well be that `Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *` and `Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true` are **incompatible** - if you want to pass credentials, you will need to respond with `Access-Control-Allow-Origin: {value-of-Origin-request-header}` and `Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true`.

Comment: As you may have noticed, I've already had the Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true as well as Access-Control-Allow-Headers:X-API-KEY included, so the only question about your suggestion remains - what is {value-of-Origin-request-header} if not ANY domain if I specified  Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *?

Comment: Basically, retrieve the value of the Origin request header (which will be the scheme://domain:port of the page which is requesting the resource) and 'mirror' that back in the ACAO response header.